# How to assign new parameters to an existing quantum circuit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, vqe

Say I have a quantum circuit like this

[image: Circuit]

This is an ansatz for solving linear equation provided in the [Qiskit's textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/vqls.html#2.-The-Algorithm)

In the textbook, it was shown how to find the optimal parameters of this ansatz such that the cost function is minimized. I want to assign the array of optimal parameters to this ansatz. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`assign_parameters()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.assign_parameters.html) method:

```
circ.assign_parameters(params, inplace=True)
```

where `params` is the array of optimal parameters.